# Setting the content size of a view inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have to lay out a few views in a View Controller which should look like this when run.

[image]

Initially the white view should be partially covering the blue view at the bottom like shown in the image. The blue view should stay put while the white view at the bottom can be scrolled over the blue view.

I added the blue view to the main UIView of the view controller. Then added a UIScrollView on top of blue view and added the white view on to the scroll view.

Now I'm getting the dreaded ambigeous content size error. I have pinned the scrollview on all four sides. Then added leading, bottom and trailing constraints to the white view. Then I tried adding a top constraint to the white view but the error still persisted. I also adding a height constraint to the white view to no avail.

It might be dofficult to imagine my setup so I added a demo project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/431nlm2ortt1404/ProfileView.zip?dl=0) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set the constraints for you [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b4h5qg0xu614bs5/ProfileView.zip?dl=0).

Explanation:
You are getting ambigous content size because your scrollView does not know its content (white view's) width and height.

I added top,width and height constraint to white view. This way your scrollView knows its content width and will scroll only vertically. As for content height - u can change heightContstrait's constant in code, or completely remove height constraint if you use autolayout properly for white view's subviews.

Comment: Thank you. That indeed works. However there's a small problem I'm facing with setting the top constraint to the white view. Becuase I've made the height of the blue view dynamic. It takes 6/10 of the main view. So it'll look proportional in every screen size. But once I set the white view's top constraint to the superview, no matter how blue view's height changes, the white view stays the same place. Is there a way to dynamically change the top constraint of the white view?

Comment: You could try connecting topConstraint to outlet, and then in code (in viewDidLayoutSubviews) set its constant to for example some proportion of blue view's height:  topConstraint.constant = 0.75 * 6 * view.frame.size.height/10;  or if you have blueView's outlet directly:  topConstraint.constant = 0.75 * blueView.frame.size.height

Comment: Got it. Thank you 

Answer (score 0):

Put the blue view under scrollview. And set scrollviews content inset, to make your white view appear not on top, but with some space. Now on start you get white view a bit over blue, and on scroll it covers blue view. About size errors, scrollview needs to know it’s content size initially. I assume your white view is table view, so set it’s bottom constraint to zero. If you want blue size to change it’s size on scrolling, like it’s avatar or something, it’s a bit different. You should take scrolling events on uiscrolldelegate, and change blue views height accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've read (and understand) Apple TN2154: "UIScrollView And Autolayout", which explains the steps required.

Looks like you're not specifying the content size properly.